# A "comparison theorem" for real analytic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n\geq2$, and $f$, $g$ two real analytic functions on $D$. Suppose on $D$ we have
\begin{equation} \label{1}
0\leq f(x)\leq g(x).
\end{equation} 
Suppose the Taylor series at some $x_{0}\in D$, associated to these functions, are
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{\alpha}a_{\alpha}(x-x_{0})^{\alpha}$$ and
 $$g(x)=\sum\limits_{\alpha}b_{\alpha}(x-x_{0})^{\alpha}.$$
Now suppose that the Taylor series of $g$ converges for $||x-x_{0}||<r$ ($r>0$ fixed, and $||.||$ the Euclidean norm). Can we conclude, **since $f$ is real analytic on the whole of $D$**  (and the above inequalities), that the Taylor's series of $f$ also converges for $||x-x_{0}||<r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=1$, $D=(-1,1)$, $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$, $g(x)=2$ and $x_0=0$. Then $f$ and $g$ are analytic on $D$ and $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in D$, but the radii of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ and $g$ around $x_0$ are $1$ and $\infty$ respectively.

Comment: Julian Aguirre. Thank you.